# How to implement clock_settime on Windows 7 + Visual Studio?

Tags: c, linux, windows, cross-platform

I want to implement the function `clock_gettime` and `clock_settime` on Windows 7 with Visual Studio, but I don't know which windows API can do this.

Comment: thanks, the question seems duplicated.